# Multiplicity of a root

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Let $f(x)$ be a polynomial of degree $n$ with $a$ as one of its roots in F[x], where F is a field. If $f'(a) \neq 0$ but $f''(a) = 0$, then what is the multiplicity of $a$?
I am studying seperable extension, I am just trying to think of possible cases..

Comment: So you are given that $a$ is a root, but $f(a)$ is not equal to $0$?

Comment: To confirm - is it supposed to be $f'(a) = 0$ or $f''(a) = 0$?

Comment: I guess you mean $f(a)=0,\;f'(a)\ne 0,\;\;f''(a)= 0$

Comment: yes you right..

Comment: Welcome to math.SE! This question is missing context or other details: Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write $f(x)=(x-a)^k q(x)$ with $k>0,\,$ and $q\,$ a polynomial with a degree less than $n$. Then using the product rule you have
$$f'(x)=k(x-a)^{k-1}q(x)+(x-a)^k q'(x)= (x-a)^{k-1}\Big(k q(x) + (x-a)q'(x)\Big)$$
If $k>1$ you would have $f'(a)=0$ which contradicts your assumption. So the order of the zero is $k=1.$ Whether $f''(a)$ is zero is relevant only if $f'(a)=0.$

Answer (score 0):

The multiplicity of $a$ is one because $f(a) = f'(a) = 0$ while $f''(a) \neq 0$. In general, the multiplicity of the root $x = a$ is

$$ \operatorname{mult}_a(f) = \max \{k \in \mathbb{N}_0 \, | \, f(a) = f'(a) = \dots = f^{(k-1)}(a) = 0, f^{(k)}(a) \neq 0 \}. $$

Comment: sorry there was a mistake .. check the edited one..

Comment: I assume we work over a field of characteristic zero.

Comment: thanks levap!! I appriciate your answer!! :)

Answer (score 0):

As $f'(a)\ne 0$, the curve does cross the $x$ axis with an angle at $a$ and the root is simple.

$f''(a)=0$ says that the curve has an inflection point at $a$ at the same time, but this doesn't impact the multiplicity.

Example: $f(x)=x^3-x,f'(x)=3x^2-1,f''(x)=6x$, at $x=0$.

[image]